# Is there a way to get solidity code from bytecode

Tags: solidity, bytecode, optimization, decompilers

Recently I had used solidity optimizer. And after reading more about how it works I was interested in trying to go deeper. One of the things I wanted to do was to see how the "solidity" code looks after it was optimized.

Basically, I would like to find a tool that can translate bytecode back to solidity.

Anyone ever heard of something like that? Because it would be an amazing learning tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This tool decompiles Ethereum contract bytecode into more readable Solidity-like code:

https://ethervm.io/decompile